# How can I get this program to print out the numbers the user entered?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class InputSum
{
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Please enter integer values (-1 to to display numbers & sum): ");

      int i = input.nextInt();
      int j = 0;

      while (i != -1)
      {
         j += i; 
         i = input.nextInt();
      }

      System.out.println("Entered Number: " + i);  
      System.out.println("The Sum: " + j);
   }
}
```

As of now my output is:

Entered Number: -1

The Sum: (Sum of the numbers entered)

Comment: You're going to have to store the numbers before overwriting i, probably to an ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

Print them inside the loop :

```
  while (i != -1)
  {
     System.out.println("Entered Number: " + i);  
     j += i; 
     i = input.nextInt();
  }

  System.out.println("The Sum: " + j);
```

Or it you want to print them in a single line :

```
  List numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  while (i != -1)
  {
     numbers.add(i); 
     j += i; 
     i = input.nextInt();
  }
  System.out.println("Entered Numbers: " + numbers);
  System.out.println("\nThe Sum: " + j);
```

Comment: On a single line isn't the stuff you entered in the console appended with print, so if you want to enter `1 2 3 -1` you'd get `1 Entered Numbers: 12 23 3-1 -1`?

Comment: @Compass You're right. I didn't think about the stuff you actually print interfering with the displayed output. If you want to print all the input in a single line, you should collect them in a List and print the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    System.out
            .print("Please enter integer values (-1 to to display numbers & sum): ");

    int i = input.nextInt();
    int j = 0;

    while (i != -1) {
        numbers.add(i);
        j += i;
        i = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Entered Numbers: ");
    for (int a = 0; a < numbers.size(); a++) {
        System.out.print(" " + numbers.get(a));
    }
    System.out.println("The Sum: " + j);
}
```

This should work to print the numbers.  You can use an arraylist to store the numbers and then if you need them for later calculations they are still stored in the arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

```
        package net.rajkannan.stackoverflow;

        import java.util.*;

        public class InputSum {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out
                        .print("Please enter integer values (-1 to to display numbers & sum): ");

                int i = input.nextInt();
                int j = 0;
                String numbers = "";

                while (i != -1) {
                    j += i;
                    numbers = numbers + i + " ";
                    i = input.nextInt();
                }

                System.out.println("Entered Numbers: " + numbers);
                System.out.println("The Sum: " + j);
            }
        }
```